# How do reverts who were models cope with online photos?

Tags: practical-islam, women, hijab, conversion

How would a (famous) model or porn star etc cope if they reverted to Islam and wore the hijaab / modest Islamic dress but had a presence on the Internet or in magazines of their previous life in scantily clad or naked photos / videos. Media and people could mock / blackmail them saying "look at them now but look how they use to be."

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE!  Interesting question; I'm having this same problem (except the "model" part).